# Shave off first 7 characters of a string in PHP

Tags: php, string

If I have a string that looks like `"s="0">hello how are you doing today` and I need it to be only `hello how are you doing today`, how can I shave off those first 7 characters in PHP?

I think one would use the length and take a sub string from place 6 to the length, but that seems inefficient. Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: RTLM: http://php.net/substr

Comment: 1) why do you think it's inefficient? 2) `substr` allows you to only specify the start position.

Comment: will it always be those specific seven characters? and will it always be seven characters? How does the program arrive at the decision that those seven characters need to be removed? from what you've given us, the answer is "yes, that is the most efficient way", but I suspect there's more to this than that, and we could possibly do the finding and replacing all in one go, which would indeed be more efficient. But that would require you to tell us more about what you're doing.

Comment: Seems like the most efficient way in something like PHP... what else had you in mind? Setting a pointer to the 7 element of the character array?

Comment: Use this: `echo substr($string, 7);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:-

```
$str = substr($str, 7,strlen($str));
```

It will select a sub string starting from 7th position till the length of the string.

Comment: why downvoted ??? That was just a confusion.

Comment: I haven't down-voted (but you were down-voted while your answer was to use `trim()`, which wasn't really appropriate), though I'd suspect it's because the OP mentions in the question that he doesn't feel this is 'efficient' (for unknown reasons). So while it's probably the best approach, it's recommending something the OP's explicitly said he didn't want. And, *now*, it looks you just copy-pasted Joe's comment from the question.

Comment: @DavidThomas: OP isn't always be well-informed (as is the case here), so explaining why `substr` is efficient is a reasonable answer in my opinion.

Comment: @David I know trim() is used to truncate whitespaces but it was just a confusion. Thinking while typing. ;)

Comment: @Blender: I didn't criticise as such, or vote either way; but the down-votes occurred while the answer was, at best, wrong. And now that it's able to solve the problem, those votes could/should be reversed by whoever voted. On the other hand, there is no explanation as to *why* this isn't inefficient, or why it's the best approach.

Comment: @Vivek: You don't need to specify that third parameter: *If `length` is omitted, the substring starting from `start` until the end of the string will be returned.*